# Tornado Project Structure : Js files not being found

Tags: python, tornado

I need to set up a project which contains HTML, CSS, and JS files. Currently, my structure is:

**project/:**

- static (css and js files)
- templates (html)
  app.py (Where the server starts)

But When I run app.py i.e

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # self.write("Hello, world")
        self.render("/full/path/to/file.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8050)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I get this:

> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/style.css (127.0.0.1)
> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/scriptfile.js (127.0.0.1)

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. I even changed the relative path to full paths of the JS and CSS files.

Answer (score 2):

Tornado Project Structure :

```sh
project
├── app.py
├── common
│   ├── db_manip.py
│   └── utils.py
├── handlers
│   ├── base_handler.py
│   ├── news_handlers.py
│   └── user_handlers.py
├── static
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── logo1.png
│   └── index.js
├── templates
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── main.html
│   ├── profile.html
│   ├── signin.html
│   └── sources.html
└── requirements.txt
```

Ok, since we have *static* in *template* folders in the *root* then:

1. Define `static_path` and `template_path` in your settings, it is directory from which static files will be served:

```py
settings = {
    "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    ...

}
```

2. Provide this settings to your application:

```py
app = tornado.web.Application(settings=settings, **kwargs)
```

3. Use `static_url` for your JS files in templates (see [`RequestHandler.static_url`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.static_url)):

```html
<script src="{{ static_url('index.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what a complete `main` would look like:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    settings = {
        "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        "cookie_secret": "_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
        "login_url": "/login",
        "db": db,
        "debug": True,
        "xsrf_cookies": True
    }

    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers=[(r'/', MainHandler),
                  (r'/sources', SourceHandler),
                  (r'/login', LoginHandler),
                  (r'/signin', SigninHandler),
                  (r'/profile', ProfileHandler),
                  (r'/favicon.ico', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings['static_path'])),
                  ],
        **settings
    )

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Server has shut down.')
```

The same goes for `css` files.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `StaticFileHandler` to your `application`

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/static/(.*)", web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "/var/www"}),
])
```

and here is the documentation [tornado.web.StaticFileHandler](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler)

Comment: I added this under after the MainHandler class and still getting the same error:  
    `                                                                                                                               
  settings = {
    "static_path": "./path/to/static/"

}
if __name__ == '__main__':
 application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
     dict(path=settings['static_path'])),], 
     **settings)
 application.listen(8050)
 tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()  `

Comment: It is, however, detecting the css file which is placed in the same directory as the js file.

Comment: Try to use `(r"/static/(.*)", web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "absolute path"})` without `settings`?

Comment: After removing the static in (r"/static/(.*) ), its working for me. So now I just add  (r"(.*) ).